# How to update the password of a Supabase user on a NextJs project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, blitz.js

I'm facing an issue updating a password for a supabase user on a BlitzJs (NextJs) project.

Basically, I have a reset password method that works perfectly. First I send an email with a reset link, that opens a page where the user can update his password like so:

```js
const { error, data } = await supabase.auth.api.updateUser(token, { password: password.trim() })
```

the token being the one in the url, provided in the email link.

So far, so good, but when I try to update the password for a logged in user, using the exact same method `supabase.auth.api.updateUser`, it fails to find the user;
The difference is the token is the `session.access_token`

So I've tried to use the `supabase.auth.api.updateUserById` method, but it gives me another error: `{ message: 'User not allowed', status: 401 }`

Any ideas? I feel the supabase docs about this is not very clear, and probably outdated as it doesn't show all the available methods :/

Answer (score -1):

## Update password for authenticated user.

```
const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.update({password: 'new password'})
```

### For more informations check: [Supabase references](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-update)